# error in xcorr2 of B&W image obtained by im2bw (image) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a problem: when I try to obtain a xcorr2 of a B&W image obtained from conversion RGB image to B&W:

```
img=im2bw(image);
c=xcorr2(img,img);
```

matlab return the following message:

```
Undefined function 'conj' for input arguments of type 'logical'.

Error in xcorr2 (line 24)
c = conv2(a, rot90(conj(b),2));
```

can I solve it?

thx ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast `img` as a `double` since it is a `logical` which is incompatible with `xcorr2`. The error is a little unclear since the error is actually thrown by `conj` which is called *inside* of `xcorr2`.

```
img = im2bw(image);

% Explicitly convert it to a double
imgd = double(img);

% Now perform cross correlation
c = xcorr2(imgd, imgd);
```